# Adding a new string value to the existing string with comma separated in python

Tags: python

I wanted to add strings to the already existing string with comma separtaed values.

For example
old_string = 'a@q'
Now if I get one new_string1= 'b@q'

Then what I need is old_string = 'a@q,b@q'

Then if I get new_string2='c@q'

Then What I should get here is old_string='a@q,b@q,c@q'

What I tried here is

```
 my_string='a@q'
>>> new_string='b@q'
>>> my_string=','.join(new_string)
>>> my_string
'b,@,q'
```

But that is not output I am expecting here. I am new to python .Can some one help me in this

Comment: `str.join` will join an iterable of strings on whatever `str` is. So `','.join("somestring")` will join all of the characters of `"somestring"` with commas

Comment: You should `join` **list**, which means concatenating a list of strings with a specified delimiter:  `','.join(['a@q', 'b@q'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an iterable list and `join` on that.

```py
','.join([old_string, new_string])
```

Answer (score 0):

`.join` usually adds items in lists. I will concatenate two strings with `+` operator and add to my_string:

```
my_string+=","+new_string
```

Now my_string will be `'a@q,b@q'`

If you have two different variables and want to concatenate them:

```
old_string='a@q'
new_string='b@q'
my_string=old_string+","+new_string
```

Comment: Actually, `join` is a method on str that joins a list with that str.